# Cannot display labels for specific data points in MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I want to display labels for specific data points in MSChart pie chart winform application with the following code

```
if (Accountchart.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < Accountchart.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
         {
             double calc=(yValues[i] * 100 / (double)totalTimeSpent);
             if ( calc< 10.00)
             Accountchart.Series[i].Points[i]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
          }
  }
```

But getting the following error while executing the code segment in if block second time

[Screenshot]![[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad6c6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You probably ONLY have Series[0], I guess.**

Series[i] looks like a mistake to me - in the whole context of this code.

So, when i==1 (the second time through), the Series[i] does NOT exist! Thus the exception, cause index is out of range.

**But it is only a guess!**
I think You in fact wanted to write: Series[0].......  in the IF-command, just like in the lines above the for loop.